# Find one of three tables from the primary key of the table

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have 3 tables, one with 14 attributes and a primary key, one with 10 attributes and a primary key and one with 6 attributes and a primary key. I have a fourth table where it stores the primary Id of one of these 3 as a foreign key inside.

How do I find which one of the three tables' primary key is this foreign key in the fourth table?

Comment: What do you mean by the table has an "attribute"?

Comment: what if two tables have same ID? how would you know which one it is? This design ehm... has some potential for improvements

Comment: @siggemannen, thats my responsibility. I put the ID in the tables, so I make sure that two tables cannot have the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` all three tables. Which ever of them is not null is the table containing that key:

```
DECLARE @Table14 TABLE (ID INT, Col1 NVARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Table10 TABLE (ID INT, Col1 NVARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Table6  TABLE (ID INT, Col1 NVARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT);

INSERT INTO @Table14 (ID, Col1) VALUES (1,'fourteen column table');
INSERT INTO @Table10 (ID, Col1) VALUES (2,'ten column table');
INSERT INTO @Table6  (ID, Col1) VALUES (3,'six column table');
INSERT INTO @Table (ID) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

SELECT *
  FROM @Table t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table14 ft
      ON t.ID = ft.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table10 tt
      ON t.ID = tt.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table6  st
      ON t.ID = st.ID
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is t, ft, tt and st. I didnt understand that. Because the table names are Table14, Table10, Table 6 and Table. Could you kindly help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: They are just aliases. You can assign an alias to a table and reference it via that. In this case I used `ft` to represent `fourteen table`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed by attribute you mean columns. You can simply query the sys objects in SQL:

```
select ic.Name as PrimaryKeyName, t.Name as TableName from sys.identity_columns ic
inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = ic.object_id
where ic.name = 'primaryIdName' and ic.is_identity = 1
and t.Name in ('your', 'table', 'names')
```

sys.tables, sys.identity, sys.all_objects, sys.all_columns are all very handy when looking for data in a new schema.